# Расчет даты поставки битрикс

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим , у нас есть таблица производственного календаря, выгруженная из 1с. Содержит поля `id`, `дата`, `тип дня( выходной, рабочий, предпраздничный)`.- это в mysql.
Известен `срок поставки`.
Как лучше вычислять дату исполнения (дата исполнения=дата начала заказа+срок поставки)?
Реально ли написать процедурку в mysql, чтобы из пхп передать нужные параметры- срок поставки и дату начала, как это будет с точки зрения оптимизации ресурсов. Как вы бы сделали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса я делаю предположение, что надо вычислить дату исполнения путем добавления к дате начала рабочих дней в количестве "срок поставки". Так же я делаю предположение, что в вашем "производственном календаре" присутствуют 365(+1) записей на каждый год. Исходя из этих предположений запрос выглядит так:

```
select max(`дата`)
  from (
    select `дата` from `календарь`
     where `тип дня`='рабочий'
       and `дата` > 'дата начала'
     order by `дата`
     limit срок_поставки
  ) A
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, с праздником! А если  срок поставки 0 дней, если праздник или выходной, то прибавить один день.

Comment: `SELECT `date` FROM 
(SELECT `date`,@tim:=IF ((SELECT `daytype` FROM `it_calendar` WHERE `date`='2016-02-23 00:00:00')!='Рабочий',1,0) AS t 
FROM `it_calendar`
     WHERE `daytype`='Рабочий'
       AND `date` >='2016-02-23 00:00:00'
     ORDER BY `date`)AS tt 
     LIMIT tt.t`
но не получается....ошибка. Наверное, надо дважды вызывать запросы для срока поставки дней 0. Первый раз  для расчета срока поставки: `SELECT @tim:=IF ((SELECT `daytype` FROM `it_calendar` WHERE `date`='2016-02-23 00:00:00')!='Рабочий',1,0) AS t ;` а потом на основании этого запроса, ваш запрос вызывать?

Comment: Да, похоже на то, лимит даже переменную с @ не дает в себя поставить, только фиксированное число. Так что вытянуть поправку на клиента и подставить непосредственно в SQL запрос количество